# Allocate more resources to EC2 service on demand

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-fargate

I'm trying to get my service to scale with the load. It's possible to configure all these capacities and values. In that case, AWS will spawn new instances of your service. You'll have multiple instances running at the same time.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/asg-capacity-limits.html

Is it possible to have it increase resources for a single instance instead? For example, add more RAM, when RAM usage is high.

Comment: You have to change instance type, to the one with more ram and/or CPU.

Comment: Maybe https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/aws-ops-automator-v2-features-vertical-scaling-preview/ is what you need but there is downtime in it's original form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cant scale vertically (bigger instance) on demand. You should build infrastructure that scales horizontally (more instances).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible but it will require stopping and terminating EC2 instances.
AutoScaling will perform [a rolling replacement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/asg-instance-refresh.html).

Comment: You can't change instance type with this solution. It's gonna be the same instance type which you have defined in the template.

Comment: A quote from the link for you "launches a set of instances with the new desired configuration". Let's read it first.

Comment: You need to check the definition of desired configuration. When you change instance type in your template, you can' go back to the previous instance type unless you change your template which kills the very definition of "auto" in autoscaling

Comment: I see. You don't like how AWS AutoScaling works. I don't work for AWS and cannot help. But this doesn't relate to this question.

Comment: It doesn't work the way you think it does. The question means, change the instance type when needed and change back to original instance type when there is less load. Which is not possible with autoscaling group.

Comment: Sorry but I will stop this discussion. You say it's not possible to switch to another EC2 instance with another instance type (with higher or lower vCPUs). I'm fine if you think so but this is not how AutoScaling works.